# Alternate for marquee tags

Tags: html, marquee

According to the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) marquee is obsolete.

What is the next proposed solution for the scrolling text. The CSS animation is a possible solution. But how to make it to work top to bottom or bottom to top.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/xxuxd/)

```
   .marquee {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 50s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: Check : http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/h7syp/

Answer (score 1):

Vertical Marquee using key-frames:

```css
.marquee {
    position: relative;
    animation: marquee 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        top: 10em
    }
    100% {
        top: -2em
    }
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">Marquee</p>
```